# How to connect SQL server 2008 to WPF app

Tags: wpf

I want to ask how can I connect sql with WPF. I searched on internet but I didn't find what I need . I need an book or article that explain each step in it . 
There is any Help?

Comment: Add System.Data.SqlClient reference to your project

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this article as it covers basic steps for using Entity framework (a very handy and powerful tool for SQL data access). http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B

Comment: I checked out the article it is usfel ,but it use the asp page Does it the same for WPF app?.
I tried to move from page to onther using the command Responde.Redirect but it doesn't  work .what should I used?

Comment: You should not mind the asp.net side. Just see how the Database is queried. If you need WPF sample here is another article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx